# Google analytics api conflicts with custom javascript api

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-analytics

We have a JavaScript API from a company they given us this following API, which we have applied to all sites.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['company']);
(function () {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://js.someone.com/ga.js' : 'http://js.someone/ga.js');
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

But it does not work when Google Analytics API is also used. How to fix so that i do not have to change variable names (http://js.someone.ga.js is a third party server there i cant change variable names?

Comment: It looks like they designed that as a _replacement_ for Google Analytics. So you're not supposed to use them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working is the variables names are the same. They're both `_gaq`.

One easy way around this is to upgrade your Google Analytics account to use [Universal Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/), and then switch your tracking code to use [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) instead of the older ga.js (which it looks like you're using).

There are many benefits to using analytics.js, but in this case one huge benefit is that there won't be a naming conflict. Analytics.js uses the variable `ga` instead of `_gaq`.

Analytics.js also supports [renaming the global tracking object](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#renaming), so in case this ever happens again, you can just rename it to solve your problem.